# How can I access (to manipulate) audio bits ( binary ) And where can I learn about it?

Tags: python, npm, audio, stream, blob

I'm looking for a way to access and manipulate audio, like knowing it's frequencies.. Is there any Python or NPM library that does that?
A recommended Udemy course? what is this subject even called? Thanks.

I'm trying to use an Audio Blob created in a JS API. Any point towards the right direction will be very helpful

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow! Sadly this isn’t a great question for SO. The topic your looking for is digital signal processing, but you can find a lot out via the [audio] tag along with the language of your choice

Comment: E.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audio+python?sort=votes

Comment: https://musicinformationretrieval.com/

        https://github.com/stevetjoa/musicinformationretrieval.com

        Python Notebooks for Fundamentals of Music Processing
        https://www.audiolabs-erlangen.de/resources/MIR/FMP/C0/C0.html

        Audio and Digital Signal Processing(DSP) in Python
        https://www.pythonforengineers.com/audio-and-digital-signal-processingdsp-in-python/

        Signal processing (scipy.signal)
        https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html

Comment: @Scott Stensland
That first link was pretty much spot on what I was looking for.
Thank you very much.

Comment: I strongly suggest you roll up your sleeves and teach yourself how to read a WAV file which is about two pages of code you write from scratch ... once you can read then create code to write a WAV file ... do not use any libraries for this ... doing such will expose you to raw audio ... initially do this for a WAV file codec  which has bit depth of 8 bits then enhance to handle multiple byte audio samples namely audio with a bit depth of 16 bits ... even if you intend to use libraries later achieving this skill set now will play back in spades later on